# Swap partition won't mount!

Tags: partitioning, mount, swap

I'm using Ubuntu 14.0 32bit on my PC. When Ubuntu  starts it won't mount swap partition and every time I have to enable it manually using GParted.

**/etc/fstab**

```
#/etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=a8375b84-987c-4270-85ac-0accd8682008 /  ext4    errors=remount-ro     0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=c399c299-23f2-4c06-b6b7-aab8ef70d98b none   swap  sw   0  0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5d8d832e-a440-45b7-b3fe-4793f0b678f3 /media/omid/Backup auto 
nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Also when I open System Monitor, I see that Swap is not available. What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to use an encrypted swap?

Comment: It doesn't matter really. I just want it to work. My home folder isn't encrypted.

Comment: What does the output of `sudo swapon -a` say?

Comment: BTW: swap partitions are not meant to be mounted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using encrypted swap you should remove this line

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw,noauto 0 0
```

And un-comment this one (remove the #)

```
#UUID=c399c299-23f2-4c06-b6b7-aab8ef70d98b none   swap  sw   0  0
```

Comment: Yes. I meant to add that to check and make sure it's correct.